# Creating a pause menu in Xcode SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have been developing by game for some time now and I am now trying to code in a pause menu. I have been looking through forums and videos but i still do not understand how to implement in a pause menu. I have a little pause button in the top left corner which i want to click to pause. Then it to overlay a menu, such as changing the z position of items so they are now visible. And then there be buttons such as resume and main menu which respectively do what they are called. I am still quite new to coding so any help would be appreciated. I am working with falling objects and a moving player so if i need to freeze them all, then unfreeze once resumed that might be a solution I am not sure. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I've tried various ways to do this, but not found a satisfactory method that works for any app/game. A lot of it will depend on how your game works. As a starting point, you probably need to look at someway of pausing the SKScene - this should halt a lot of the animation (but you may have to do extra work).

You could add some kind of blur effect or overlay and then add an unpause button and then pause the scene. Touches will still be detected when paused, but you won't have any animation or updates happening after the pause. The following code should work to pause the scene.

```
let pauseAction = SKAction.run {
  self.isPaused = true
  debugPrint("Paused")
}
self.run(pauseAction)
```

The reason to pause the scene in an action is that any addChild calls won't be processed if you set isPaused directly. actuallyPaused is just a bool variable to keep track of wether the scene should be paused or not (if the parent view is un-paused, the scene would also be un-paused). Btw, You do not need to use an action to set isPaused to false.

You probably also should look at implementing observers for

```
NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive
NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground
NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground
```

as you will also need to know when your game has been sent to background either via control center or the home button.